# Oracle MERGE: only NOT MATCHED is triggered

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, match, on-clause

Database: **Oracle**

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_FOR_TESTS (
    d DATE,
    t NUMBER(8)
)
```

MERGE:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_FOR_TESTS
    USING DUAL
    ON ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_FOR_TESTS) = 1)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET T = T+1
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN         
        INSERT (D, T) VALUES (sysdate, 1)
```

or

```
    ...
    ON ((SELECT T FROM TABLE_FOR_TESTS) is not null)
    ...
```

I will refer to the first version of MERGE, but the second one has the same effect.

1) I run that MERGE for the first time

- result: **expected** (because there is no element, the ON condition is false => **INSERT**)

2) Here I run:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_FOR_TESTS
```

and it's output is "1".

3) I run that MERGE for the second time

- result: **unexpected** (**INSERT**), expected: UPDATE (it works only on sqlfiddle)

---

Why is **ON** condition false at the N-th run (N>1) ? ( if it was "1" as output at 2) )

(just to test: if I change the condition to be `ON (1=1)` before the second run, it works well: UPDATE is done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood what merge is for.

I would expect your table to be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_FOR_TESTS (
    d DATE,
    t NUMBER(8),
    CONSTRAINT TABLE_FOR_TESTS_PK PRIMARY KEY (d)
)
```

and then the merge statement could be:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_FOR_TESTS t
  USING (SELECT trunc(sysdate) d FROM DUAL) s
    ON (s.d = t.d)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET t = t+1
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN         
    INSERT (d, t) VALUES (trunc(sysdate), 1)
```

where the join is on the primary key of the table and either update or insert depending on whether the record for that PK value exists.

This would have a maximum of one record per day and t would hold the number of executions of this statement per day (assuming no other DML on TABLE_FOR_TESTS).

Note: sysdate by itself includes a time component. trunc(sysdate) removes it and sets the time to 00:00:00.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted to achieve. I wrote only a simplified example here.