# A way to update data in Oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table that I need to update each day. The data comes in a text file every time. I wrote a program that extracts the data from the text file and and writes it in the table, but now I want to modify it to just update the existing data. The data is mostly the same, it might differ only a few things.

I was thinking about `MERGE` but I don't know very well how I could use this in my program. All the examples that I saw used a second table.

So it would be like creating a second table in which I extract the current data, after which I make the merge into the old table to update the records. I want to avoid creating a second table, so I was wondering if there is any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451727/oracle-merge-only-not-matched-is-triggered you can find something interesting. Use MERGE only if you want an INSERT/UPDATE. Notice that MERGE is not atomic.

Comment: Seems like a typical use case for `MERGE` - where's your problem?

Comment: How are you extracting the data from the file? Are you using `EXTERNAL TABLE`? If yes, then simply use UPDATE statement to update only those records which are new. Or, even better is `MERGE` so that you can `INSERT WHEN NOT MATCHED` and `UPDATE WHEN MATCHED`.

Comment: @curiosu Care to elaborate? How is `MERGE` not atomic?

Comment: I mean, if you want to INSERT if there is not line or UPDATE if there is a line ... you can have problems in a multithreading environment. If the first MERGE(INSERT) was done, the second MERGE can fail. (both see no row, but after the first one there is a row)

Comment: This is tagged both Oracle and MySQL.  Which of the two databases are you using?  The syntax for `MERGE` and the set of valid options will often differ between databases.